# Excerpt isn't working or am I missing something?

Tags: loop, excerpt

I thought that by default when you loop content (like blog posts) in a WordPress the content is limited to 55 characters. I have not touched my functions.php file yet for when I loop the posts the article/ content is published in full.

My loop is like this - should the content tag be different?

```
<?php

if( have_posts() ):

    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <p>Posted on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></p>

        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

        <hr>

    <?php endwhile;

endif;

?>
```

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not. The length limit is for excerpt, which should be called manually. To get the excerpt in your loop, you should use:

```
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
```

Instead of:

```
<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
```

If you thought of this because of the option in the reading section of settings:

[image: Excerpt for feeds]

Then you have to notice, this is for RSS feeds, which can be accessed at:

> www.example.com/feed